# Angular data undefined

Tags: angular

I have a problem with some code:

I want to make a quotation with retrieving three collections items from DB. (function to load are ok).

The first one works, but the next two (which needs data from the first) are not working. It says undefined.

Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.campaignService.getOneCampaign(id).then(
      (campaign: Campaign) => {
        this.campaign = campaign;
        if (campaign.camptype = "VIDEO") {
          this.unitcostvid = (Math.round(this.campaign.unitcost * this.campaign.durationvid * 10000)) / 10000;
          this.totalcost = this.unitcostvid * this.campaign.nbuser;
        }
        if (campaign.camptype = "MAIL") {
          this.unitcostvid = this.campaign.unitcost;
          this.totalcost = this.unitcostvid * this.campaign.nbuser;
        }
        if (campaign.status = "EA") {
          this.eacamp = true;
        }

        return this.campaign;
      }
    )
    if (this.campaign) {
      this.usercService.getSingleUserc(this.campaign.usercidvalidate).then(
        (userc: Userc) => {
          this.userc = userc;
          return this.userc;
        }
      )
    }
    if (this.campaign) {
      this.companyService.getCompanybycoid(this.campaign.coid).then(
        (company: Company) => {
          this.company = company;

          return this.company;
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

I want to have `campaign`, `company` and `userc` values, but I only get `campaign`

Please help me.

Comment: Your if statements are outside of the promise scope so they may be executed before the 'then' function

Answer (score 0):

First please change the campaign.camptype = "VIDEO" to campaign.camptype == "VIDEO"
                         campaign.camptype = "MAIL" to campaign.camptype == "MAIL"
                         campaign.status = "EA" to campaign.status == "EA"

then run again

Comment: This part works.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigning campaign in `then` section, but trying to use them as a next statement which happens *before* `then`  section executes. 
Move it all inside like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.campaignService.getOneCampaign(id).then(
        (campaign: Campaign) => {
            this.campaign = campaign;
            if (campaign.camptype === "VIDEO") {
                this.unitcostvid = (Math.round(this.campaign.unitcost * this.campaign.durationvid * 10000)) / 10000;
                this.totalcost = this.unitcostvid * this.campaign.nbuser;
            }
            if (campaign.camptype === "MAIL") {
                this.unitcostvid = this.campaign.unitcost;
                this.totalcost = this.unitcostvid * this.campaign.nbuser;
            }
            if (campaign.status === "EA") {
                this.eacamp = true;
            }

            // no need to return this
            //return this.campaign;

            if (this.campaign) {
                this.usercService.getSingleUserc(this.campaign.usercidvalidate).then(
                    (userc: Userc) => {
                        this.userc = userc;
                        return this.userc;
                    }
                )
            }
            if (this.campaign) {
                this.companyService.getCompanybycoid(this.campaign.coid).then(
                    (company: Company) => {
                        this.company = company;

                        return this.company;
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

and I changed `=` to `===` as I suppose you wanted to compare and not assign...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems.

The first is that you are setting the values in some of your `if` statements, rather than checking for equality.

The second, and the reason for `campaign` being undefined is that the code that uses it runs before the code that sets it. As you are using a Promise, the code within the `then` is running after the data is finished loading in your service.

To get around this, you can set the users and company within your then callback function:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.campaignService.getOneCampaign(id).then(
      (campaign: Campaign) => {
        this.campaign = campaign;
        if (campaign.camptype == "VIDEO") {
          this.unitcostvid = (Math.round(this.campaign.unitcost * this.campaign.durationvid * 10000)) / 10000;
          this.totalcost = this.unitcostvid * this.campaign.nbuser;
        }
        if (campaign.camptype == "MAIL") {
          this.unitcostvid = this.campaign.unitcost;
          this.totalcost = this.unitcostvid * this.campaign.nbuser;
        }
        if (campaign.status == "EA") {
          this.eacamp = true;
        }

        if (this.campaign) {
            this.usercService.getSingleUserc(this.campaign.usercidvalidate).then(
              (userc: Userc) => {
                this.userc = userc;
              }
            )
          }

          if (this.campaign) {
            this.companyService.getCompanybycoid(this.campaign.coid).then(
              (company: Company) => {
                this.company = company;
              }
            )
          }
      }
    )
}
```